# classifying the actual weather data of Cfb climate to dry, normal and wet periods

Tags: meteorology

I have 3 years weather data of a region in Austria, and I want to classify a year to dry, normal and wet periods, how I can analyse this data of such climate?

Thanks

Comment: How would you define *dry, normal and wet*? And if you don't tell what kind of data you have, nobody can answer.